# Java older versions support in windows 10

Tags: java, windows-10

I want know what is the minimum java version required for windows 10?

We have a requirement to install java 1.4 in windows 10.

Is it possible?

Comment: What makes you think that Windows has a minimum requirement on Java in any way? Did you try installing this old version and run into problems? If yes, what errors do you get?

Comment: I think the question is just "can I install java 1.4 on windows 10?"

Comment: @Abhijit please stop making useless edits. If you get too many rejections you lose the ability to suggest edits.

Comment: You should run `java.exe` or `javaw.exe` in the compatibility mode to windows xp. In any case - this is generally have no sense to use Java 1.4 now days, you can use Java 1.8 it can run the Java 1.4 code/byte code (but not java 9-10-11 etc)

Comment: [I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/), i.e. simply trying to do the install and see what happens.

Comment: @UnholySheep we an application running with java1.4 version and client wants to update the operating system to windows 10. that is why i asked that whether java1.4 works in windows 10 or not?

Comment: @LaxmiKanth That sounds like a task for your QC department, not a question for SO

Answer (score 1):

Given Java 1.4 was released more more than a decade before Windows 10 (first release in 2002, public support ended in 2008 and extended support ending in 2013), you have no guarantee what so ever that it will work correctly.

Instead you should really start working on upgrading to a newer Java version which does support Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, updating java version is not the part because already application built with java 1.4 and it's working perfectly. If we update java then lot of features are removed in later versions of java. It's a big problem, that is why we thought of not updating java.

Comment: @LaxmiKanth _"lot of features are removed in later versions of java"_ that is not true for Java versions until Java 8, and for higher versions, there are alternatives or replacements. Seriously, being stuck on a Java version which has been out of (extended) support for 5 years and out of public support for 10 is a bad idea, especially from a security perspective. Also, unless you did really weird things, your application will probably run just fine on Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the below java 1.4 archive download , no specific Windows version is the dependency apart from the type of System(32,64 bit). So just go ahead downloading java specific to type of System and it should work.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html